# React component keeps re-rendering whenever screen is minimized or another tab is opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web, rendering

I have a component in my portfolio website that creates a diagonally moving circle every couple of seconds. The problem is that when I minimize the screen or change the tab and come back after a minute, many circles will be created at the same time and the screen gets filled with them. I am not sure why this happens.

You can see the effect live in my website: https://khaledalhariri.com

Currently I have it set to have 6 circles at most in the screen. So when I minimize the window and open it after a minute, 6 circles are created at the same time which is an issue.. if I didnt set that limit of 6 circles then countless circles would have been created at the same time.

Code:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './banner-skills.component.css';
import SKILLS_DATA, { Skill } from '../../data/skills';

const BannerSkills = () => {
  const CREATE_CIRCLE_MS = 4500;
  const CREATE_CIRCLE_MS_MOBILE = 7000;
  const ARRAY_OF_SKILLS: Skill[] = [];
  const isFirstRender = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const skillsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('banner-skills-container')[0];
    let minScreenSize = window.screen.width * 0.08;
    let maxScreenSize = window.screen.width * 0.85;
    let maxCircles = 6;
    let prevInitPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxScreenSize) - minScreenSize;

    const createDiagonalCircle = () => {
      if(window.screen.width <= 500) {
        minScreenSize = window.screen.width * 0.8;
        maxCircles = 4;
      }
      else {
        minScreenSize = window.screen.width * 0.08;
        maxCircles = 6;
      }

      if(ARRAY_OF_SKILLS.length >= maxCircles) {
        return;
      }
      
      const circle = document.createElement('div');
      circle.classList.add('skill-circle');
      skillsContainer.appendChild(circle);
      const logo = document.createElement('img');
      let randomSkill = SKILLS_DATA[Math.floor(Math.random() * SKILLS_DATA.length)];
      
      while(ARRAY_OF_SKILLS.indexOf(randomSkill) >= 0) {
        randomSkill = SKILLS_DATA[Math.floor(Math.random() * SKILLS_DATA.length)];
      }

      logo.src = randomSkill.img;
      ARRAY_OF_SKILLS.push(randomSkill);
      circle.appendChild(logo);

      let size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 70) + 70;
      circle.style.width = size + 'px';
      circle.style.height = size + 'px';

      let posTop = -150;
      let posLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxScreenSize) - minScreenSize;

      while(Math.abs(posLeft - prevInitPos) < (window.screen.width * 0.13)) {
        posLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxScreenSize) - minScreenSize;
      }
      
      prevInitPos = posLeft;
      let moveCirclesInterval = setInterval(frame, size - (size * 0.65));
      
      function frame() {
        if (posTop === 500) {
          skillsContainer.removeChild(circle);
          ARRAY_OF_SKILLS.splice(ARRAY_OF_SKILLS.indexOf(randomSkill), 1);
          clearInterval(moveCirclesInterval);
        } else {
          posTop++;
          posLeft++;
          circle.style.top = posTop + 'px';
          circle.style.left = posLeft + 'px';
          circle.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
      }
      isFirstRender.current = false;
    }

    if(isFirstRender.current === true) {
      createDiagonalCircle();
      if(window.screen.width <= 500) {
        let spawnCirclesInterval = setInterval(createDiagonalCircle, CREATE_CIRCLE_MS_MOBILE);
        return () => clearInterval(spawnCirclesInterval); 
      }
      else {
        let spawnCirclesInterval = setInterval(createDiagonalCircle, CREATE_CIRCLE_MS);
        return () => clearInterval(spawnCirclesInterval); 
      } 
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="banner-skills-container"></div>
  )
}

export default BannerSkills
```

The circles are created in the useEffect and I have tried to find out if the page is being re-redenderd or not to stop it but I didn't find anything to work.

Comment: It's because of setinterval - when you leave the page, timing is still counts, but renders stops. the simplest way to check how it works is to use simple hook and counter +1, then you go to other page and wait for some time. then when you return, you'll find that counter worked all the time.
I'm not sure which way is the best practice, but as for me [RequestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) will be prefered. But to be honest, you're using react with virtual DOM but puts animation elements via vanilla js - to real DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't cleare the interval of the setInterval function when the user navigates away from the tab or minimizes the screen. **createDiagonalCircle** continues to run in the background and creates circles even when the user is not actively viewing the page.

To fix this issue, you can use the **window.blur** and **window.focus** events to stop and restart the interval respectively. Here's an example implementation:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const skillsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('banner-skills-container')[0];
  let minScreenSize = window.screen.width * 0.08;
  let maxScreenSize = window.screen.width * 0.85;
  let maxCircles = 6;
  let prevInitPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxScreenSize) - minScreenSize;
  let intervalId: any;

  const createDiagonalCircle = () => {
    // ... rest of the code
  };

  const handleVisibilityChange = () => {
    if (document.hidden) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    } else {
      intervalId = setInterval(createDiagonalCircle, window.screen.width <= 500 ? CREATE_CIRCLE_MS_MOBILE : CREATE_CIRCLE_MS);
    }
  };

  if (window.screen.width <= 500) {
    minScreenSize = window.screen.width * 0.8;
    maxCircles = 4;
  } else {
    minScreenSize = window.screen.width * 0.08;
    maxCircles = 6;
  }

  window.addEventListener('blur', () => clearInterval(intervalId));
  window.addEventListener('focus', () => intervalId = setInterval(createDiagonalCircle, window.screen.width <= 500 ? CREATE_CIRCLE_MS_MOBILE : CREATE_CIRCLE_MS));
  document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange);

  intervalId = setInterval(createDiagonalCircle, window.screen.width <= 500 ? CREATE_CIRCLE_MS_MOBILE : CREATE_CIRCLE_MS);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    window.removeEventListener('blur', () => clearInterval(intervalId));
    window.removeEventListener('focus', () => intervalId = setInterval(createDiagonalCircle, window.screen.width <= 500 ? CREATE_CIRCLE_MS_MOBILE : CREATE_CIRCLE_MS));
    document.removeEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange);
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I managed to make it work with a few adjustments to your suggested solution. I removed the return from the useEffect and added the listeners for blur and focus. I didn't add the remove methods and didn't use the visibility change function (it didn't work when I used them).